# How can i add numbers near each line in index 0 in richTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox2.Lines.Length; i++)
{
    richTextBox2.Lines[i] = richTextBox2.Lines[i].Insert(0, i + " ");
}
```

Before that tried with the Insert:

```
richTextBox2.Lines[i].Insert(0, i + " ");
```

In both cases it's not adding any numbers.

For example if the lines are:

```
Hello world
Hi
Hello
```

Then i want it to be now:

```
1 Hello world
2 Hi
3 Hello
```

But the loop does nothing it's not adding any numbers.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/creating-line-numbers-for-richtextbox-in-c-sharp - Did you even look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't modifiy the single line in that way. If you [look at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) you will find this remark

> By default, the collection of lines is a read-only copy of the lines
>   in the TextBox. To get a writable collection of lines, use code
>   similar to the following: textBox1.Lines = new string[] { "abcd" };

So the correct way to reach you goal is

```
string[]  lines = richTextBox2.Lines;

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    lines[i] = (i+1) + " " + lines[i];
}
richTextBox2.Lines = lines;
```

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Works for me.  Maybe it's your settings.

Comment: This is the right answer, completely forgot about Lines being readonly

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Not sure what is the problem. Just tested with a simple application and works.

Comment: Now someone post an answer, with your information and @DmitryBychenko 's LINQ solution and it would be perfect. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try using *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

richTextBox2.Lines = richTextBox2
  .Lines
  .Select((line, index) => $"{index + 1} {line}")
  .ToArray();
```

please, avoid *redrawing UI* (esp. `RichTextBox`) which can slow down your application, but build the data (lines, text) and then assign it in *one go*.

Comment: @Samvel Petrosov: I've tried on `WinForms`, `.Net 4.6.1`, `VS 2017` and it does work.

Comment: @Samvel Petrosov: move the code from the *constructor* to `FormLoad` or whenever event when `RichEdit` is not empty